# How do I create custom table cells in a JTable ?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, multiline, tablecellrenderer

I would like to create a custom table that looks something like this:

```
+----------------------------------+
|  +-----+                         |
|  |     |   [Some JLabel]         |
|  |Icon |   [Some other JLabel]   |
|  +-----+                         |
+----------------------------------+
```

I currently have the following setup:

```
 //scroll view for the table
 JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(eventsTable);
 scrollPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
 eventsTable.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
 scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(tableWidth,500));

  //create the events table
  EventsTableView eventsTable = new EventsTableView(new EventsTableModel()){

   public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column){
                    Component c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);

                    if (!isRowSelected(row)) {

                        c.setForeground(new Color(214,214,214,255));
                        c.setBackground(new Color(27,36,50,255));

                    }else{

                        c.setForeground(new Color(40,40,40,255));
                        c.setBackground(new Color(250,250,250,255)); 


                    }
                    return c;
                }
            };

        eventsTable.setBackground(new Color(19,24,30,255));
        eventsTable.setShowHorizontalLines(false);
        eventsTable.setShowVerticalLines(false);
        eventsTable.setTableHeader(null);
        eventsTable.setIntercellSpacing(new Dimension(0,0));
        int tableWidth = 250;
```

I haven't figured the whole renderer thing out, so I am not really sure if that's the right way to do this.

Is there a way to specify a custom, say, JPanel and add labels to it and return it in a custom renderer ?

Comment: 1. Component hasn't an Icon, have to cast and to use the JLabel, 2. is required to play with vertical/horizontal text alignment, gap for Icon, 3. then easiest of ways is to use plain vanilla Html with br tag, 4. should be works untill JTable isn't filtered or sorted

Comment: for better help sooner post an SSCCE/MCVE/MCTRE, short, runnable, compilable with hardcoded value for JTable/XxxTableModel in local variable

Comment: @mKorbel Can you give me an example ? In an answer maybe ?